# Embedded SQL in C connection issue

Tags: c, postgresql, embedded-sql, ecpg

The Postgresql role is the owner of the db 'university' and it's been configured like,

> alter user canoe password 'mypassword';

The piece of embedded SQL code in C just makes a connection to DB.

> printf("SQLSTATE=[%s]\n", SQLSTATE);
>     EXEC SQL CONNECT TO 'university' USER 'canoe/mypassword'
>     printf("SQLSTATE=[%s]\n", SQLSTATE);

The code is compiled and linked. It's run on the localhost on which the postgresql server is running and listening on its default port.

> $ ecpg connection.pgc
>   $ gcc -I/usr/include/postgresql connection.c -o conn -lecpg

The output of the compiled code is:

> SQLSTATE=[00000]
>   SQLSTATE=[08001]

The error code 08001 means "sqlclient_unable_to_establish_sqlconnection". I've changed the configuration of postgresql to log all connection attempts in order to debug the code.

> LOG:  parameter "log_connections" changed to "on"
>   LOG:  00000: parameter "log_error_verbosity" changed to "verbose"

However, when the compiled code is run, there is no any error. When I connect it with pgsql, it has log info.

> $ pqsql university -W
>   LOG:  connection authorized: user=canoe database=university

The wired thing that I notice is even I enter wrong password after prompt, I can still get authorized. But my piece of C code doesn't work.

I can't resolve the issue or have any idea to debug it further. Any idea to where is the issue?

Comment: I really don't recommend writing new code in ecpg without a really good reason. It's very little used and not very well supported. It works, and is widely deployed for a lot of legacy apps, though.

Comment: I agree that ESQL is terrible; especially the interaction with the C preprocessor is a PITA. But everybody should at least be allowed to be exposed to it just once...